# Creating new EventSource using Powershell differs to C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, system.diagnostics

I am creating a new EventLog EventSource, and I use my own custom set of categories.

I currently do this in C# code with the following:

```
var eventSourceData = new EventSourceCreationData(sourceName, logName)
                                      {
                                          CategoryCount = AllCategories.Count(),
                                          CategoryResourceFile = resourceFilePath,
                                          ParameterResourceFile = resourceFilePath,
                                          MessageResourceFile = resourceFilePath
                                      };

EventLog.CreateEventSource(eventSourceData);
```

I have now converted this to a powershell script like this:

```
New-eventlog -logname $Log -ComputerName $ComputerName -Source $Source -CategoryResourceFile $categoryDllPath -MessageResourceFile $categoryDllPath -ErrorVariable Err -CategoryCount 20
```

Notr **-CategoryCount 20** at the end, my script fails on this argument saying it is not a valid parameter. (Which it seems not to be)

So my question is, using Powershell how can I provide the CategoryCount so that the logging works correctly?

Thanks so much.

The error message is `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CategoryCount'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, `New-EventLog` doesn't support CategoryCount.

But you can still use .NET classes directly in Powershell, so something like this should work:

```
$eventSourceData = new-object System.Diagnostics.EventSourceCreationData("$SourceName", "$logName")  
$eventSourceData.CategoryCount = 20
$eventSourceData.CategoryResourceFile = $CategoryDllPath
$eventSourceData.MessageResourceFile = $CategoryDllPath

If (![System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($eventSourceData.Source))
{      
[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource($eventSourceData)  
}
```